# where could we get such a landscape GIS layer

Tags: r, plot, geospatial, layer, geo

Here, I found a landscape GIS layer is really attractive, especially for presenting species/samples distributions. I would like to know if it can be reached in R or any other resources?

The GIS layer were used in Fig 1. in this article (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1469-8137.2010.03479.x/full).

This Fig 1 image is here:

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1111/j.1469-8137.2010.03479.x/asset/image_t/NPH_3479_f1_thumb.gif?v=1&t=gsk5sbhs&s=e5e2e4bbb194f799f7ab9bec85a416e295405784
[image]

I have ever tried to submit this question in R-sig-geo. But, I failed. I expect to get some helps/directions here.

Thanks a lots for any directions.

Best wishes,

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm guessing you want to plot some points on top of a pretty map image. Yes? See packages sp, rgdal, and raster.

Comment: Dear Spacedman, I expect to get such a layer as presented in this Fig 1. I have be known with some R functions for plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feng,
if I read the Google docs correctly, you can modify the labels and displayed features with the extra parameters style and element.
I did not include custom parameters for these in the RgoogleMaps package, however, you can easily pass ANY addition parameters via the path argument !
If you read the help file for GetMap carefully, you will note the following example:

## note that since the path string is just appended to the URL you can "abuse" the path argument to pass anything to the query, e.g. the style parameter:

#The following example displays a map of Brooklyn where local roads have been changed to bright green and the residential areas have been changed to black:
   ## Not run:  GetMap(center='Brooklyn', zoom=12, maptype = "roadmap", path = "&style=feature:road.local|element:geometry|hue:0x00ff00|saturation:100&style=feature:landscape|element:geometry|lightness:-100", sensor='false', destfile = "MyTile4.png",  RETURNIMAGE = FALSE);

Hope this helps,

Markus Loecher

Comment: Dear Markus, Thanks a lot for your kind direction. Now, I got much clear with GetMap() function. I think what I need to data is to read Google docs and then tuning path argument of GetMap().

Comment: But can you publish a google maps image? Is that ok with the terms of service?

Answer (score 2):

It is very possible to download this file and read it in with R, configure it to have the correct geo-coordinates so that overplotting works easily, and showing the image with the right colour scheme and so on. But, automating getting all of the data you need is not so easy.

*You need the colour table from the GIF file so that you can plot the correct set of RGB values for each pixel (the information is in the file, but I'm not sure if this can be obtained directly with R, I will check - it certainly can be with GDAL, but extracting those values in an automated way depends on various tools being available).*

UPDATE: **It turns out that the raster package gets hold of the colour information correctly and plots it, see below.**

You also need the geo-spatial information, i.e. the coordinates of a reference pixel (say, the top left pixel corner), and the scale (the geographic width and height of the pixels) and this information is not stored in the file. Also, the coordinate system of the file is not in the file, and very likely not provided explicitly with the image data.

If the colours and the coordinate system were stored with the file, then it would all be easy and something like the following would be enough.

(Note this worked for me once, but then I think subsequent requests are blocked by the server, so try to only download the file one time).

```
u <- "http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1111/j.1469-8137.2010.03479.x/asset/image_n/NPH_3479_f1.gif?v=1&t=gskxvi17&s=0f13fa9dae78bd6837aeee594065c6ca112864d2"

imfile <- paste(tempfile(), ".gif", sep = "")

download.file(u, imfile, mode = "wb")

library(raster)  ## rgdal also required for this file format
library(rgdal)

im <- raster(imfile)

plot(im)
```

This looks fine but now see that there is no "real-world" coordinate system, this is just an axis from pixel 1 to the number in the X dimension (and same for Y).

```
 axis(1, pos = 2)
```

[image: Correct colour plot, but no real coordinate system]

So, still we need manually work to discover appropriate reference coordinates for the image - and guesses here can work fine, but still they are only guesses and you may end up creating a lot of pain for something seemingly simple.

If plot points interactively is enough for you, then you might use `locator` in conjunction with `points` and `lines` and `text`, and related plotting functions.

Comment: +1 for clarity and completeness; I can't speak to correctness.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want data like this image, then there are packages to access imagery directly, again utilizing the tools in `sp` and `rgdal`. This example is close using `gmap` in the `dismo` package.

```
library(dismo)

e <- extent(-7, 5, 38, 44)

gm <- gmap(e, type = "terrain")
plot(gm)
```

[image: Very simple google maps plot]

Note that while we specify the extents in "longlat" the image comes back in its native (Google) Mercator.

```
print(gm)
```

See `?gmap` for more options on transforming your own data to match the image's projection, or the broader function set in `raster`, `rgdal` and `sp` for other options. There are other imagery providers that might be preferable, and quite a few options in the R suite of contributed packages.

Comment: Dear mdsumner. Thanks a lot for what you have given me.